# Frosty glass background effect in android activity

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am trying to apply a frosty glass effect to the background image of an activity, but I don't know how to do this can anyone know or do this kind of application if yes then help me please.

**Expected output:-**

[image]

**This is my code where I am using Blurry library but when the application run it does work as expected:-**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    long delay = 5000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_activity);

                Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .radius(25)
                        .sampling(2)
                        .async()
                        .animate(500)
                        .capture(findViewById(R.id.content))
                        .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.content));


        Timer runSplash = new Timer();
        TimerTask showSplash = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        };

        runSplash.schedule(showSplash,delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: is that background image? or u need transparent

Comment: I have to apply frost glass effect on background image. @jagapathi

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/the-blurry-frosted-background-is-a-common-pattern-on-ios-where-they-have-simply-controls-to-cbd0c5843e5f

Answer (score 0):

May be this library is helpful to you.

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2192

Comment: Thanks @R. R. M for help, it will work, but when I am writing the code in onCreate() method it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this code: 
Blurry.with(context).from(bitmap).into(imageView); 
You can also add sampling and radius to this.